# How to run mercurial changegroup hook only after a rebase?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

We have a simple mercurial hook that runs every time we pull remote changes.  We use changegroup hook.  Our hook rebuilds some dlls and copy them to a folder.  We automatically rebase when we do a pull.  This causes our hook to be run two times, first when we do the pull, then after the automatic rebase.

Is there any easy way to detect if there's going to be a rebase and only run the hook once at the end of the rebase?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your original hook?

Anyway, if you check the source parameter, you could choose if the hook should run or not:

```
def changegroup_hook(ui, repo, source, **kwargs):
    if source != 'strip':  # rebase operation uses 'strip' as source
       return 0  # SUCCESS
    # continue rebase processing
```